# CSS - Div width with strange behavior

Tags: css, html, width

I am newbie with CSS and working in this code for some hours now...

Please, can someone see this code here http://jsfiddle.net/Nm2s8/2/ and help me? When click in the title to "open" the div, it changes width, I do not know why :(

If I change in the CSS the overflow from class "winhdn" to visible, the width stays the same... for me it is a crazy behavior...

HTML:

```
<div class="resopt">
  <img class="resico" src="http://www.flashmyandroid.com/forum/images/smilie2/big_smile.png">
  <div id="win01" class="winshw">
    <div class="wintop">
      <span>Title 01</span>
    </div>
    <div class="restxt">
      estibulum iaculis lacinia est. Proin dictum elementum velit. Fusce euismod consequat ante. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sed dolor. Aliquam congue fermentum nisl. Mauris accumsan nulla vel diam. Sed in lacus ut enim adipisc aliquet. Nulla venenatis. In pede mi, aliquet sit amet, euismod in, auctor ut, ligula. Aliquam dapibus tincidunt metus. Praesent justo dolor, lobortis quis, lobortis dignissim, pulvinar ac, lorem. Vestibulum sed ante.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="resopt">
  <img class="resico" src="http://www.flashmyandroid.com/forum/images/smilie2/big_smile.png">
  <div id="win02" class="winhdn">
    <div class="wintop">
      <span>Title 02</span>
    </div>
    <div class="restxt">
      estibulum iaculis lacinia est. Proin dictum elementum velit. Fusce euismod consequat ante. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Pellentesque sed dolor. Aliquam congue fermentum nisl. Mauris accumsan nulla vel diam. Sed in lacus ut enim adipisc aliquet. Nulla venenatis. In pede mi, aliquet sit amet, euismod in, auctor ut, ligula. Aliquam dapibus tincidunt metus. Praesent justo dolor, lobortis quis, lobortis dignissim, pulvinar ac, lorem. Vestibulum sed ante.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.resopt { display:inline-block; width:100%; margin:8px 0 12px 0; }
.resopt .resico { float:left; width:34px; height:34px; margin:-10px 6px 0 2px; }
.resopt .winshw { overflow:visible; min-height:100px; border:2px solid #389CF2; border-radius:8px 8px 0 0; background-color:#E6F2FF; background-image:url(http://www.google.com/mapfiles/zoom-minus.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:right 8px top 5px; background-position-x:99%; background-position-y:5px; }
.resopt .winhdn { overflow:hidden; height:26px; border:2px solid #389CF2; border-radius:8px 8px 8px 8px; background-color:#E6F2FF; background-image:url(http://www.abertay.ac.uk/media/zoom-plus.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:right 8px top 5px; background-position-x:99%; background-position-y:5px; }
.resopt .wintop { height:26px; border-bottom:1px solid #389CF2; cursor:pointer; }
.resopt .wintop span { font-size:15; font-weight:bold; line-height:26px; color:#585858; }
.resopt .restxt { padding:10px 14px 14px 14px; font-size:15px; text-align:justify; line-height:19px; color:#484848; background-color:#F9F9F9; }
```

JS:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".wintop").click(function() {
    var newId = $(this).parent();
    if (newId.hasClass("winhdn")){
      newId.removeClass("winhdn");
      newId.addClass("winshw");
    } else {
      newId.removeClass("winshw");
      newId.addClass("winhdn");
    }
  })
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

change overflow:visible to overflow:hidden in .resopt .winshw

```
.resopt .winshw
{
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: maybe you misunderstood my question, or maybe I misunderstood your answer :), but I need this code working together with the jQuery, to change div height (show and hide)...

Answer (score 0):

It's due to "formatting context" : http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=6BC9D

**"Floats don't overlap each other, and neither will a float overlap an element that establishes a new block formatting context."**

```
                 .resopt .winshw { 
                 overflow:hidden; 
                 min-height:100px; 
                 /*.. */
                 }
```

[See here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nm2s8/3/)

Comment: Thank you newTag for the reply! Please, see this update http://jsfiddle.net/Nm2s8/4/. I'd like the div to have 100% width, but the image must stay "inside" it... well not completely "inside", just like the second update... Its kinda dificult to explain, did you understand?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did it using "position:absolute" to the image, and add extra margin-left to the title text. Here is the result: http://jsfiddle.net/Nm2s8/5/

```
.resopt .resico { position:absolute; width:34px; height:34px; margin:-10px 6px 0 2px;

.resopt .wintop span { margin-left:44px; font-size:15; font-weight:bold; line-height:26px; color:#585858; }
```

Thank you everyone! Hope this help some people in the future!